# CSS - Change image by hovering, just like this !

Tags: css, background, position

Plz take a look at this link:
[a sample site](http://arnikaweb.com/%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86)

at the bottom u see wordpress and joomla icons, when u hover on it by mouse, it seems gray icons get colored.
This is just one picture (series of images - thx to my love, Firebug !) and if i'm right it's method of background positioning.
Where can i find a good resource to learn it?
I already can do that by coding in CSS (but with two images, one for "a" and one for "a:hover" tags).
Thanks

Comment: What you're looking for is called "CSS Sprites". Try this tutorial, for example: http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/create-a-button-with-hover-and-active-states-using-css-sprites/ (found by searching for "css hover sprites")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a sprite:

[image]

Google uses one too, as it reduces the size of the served content:

[image]

To make it work properly, you clip the background image so that only a little part shows:

```
#foo
{
  background-image: url('bar.png');
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

And on `:hover`, you shift it over a bit:

```
#foo:hover
{
  background-position: 70px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As piskvor mentions this technique is often termed "CSS sprites":

```
div {
    background-image:<url-to-image>;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}

div:hover {
    background-image:<url-to-image>;
    background-position:0px 50px;
}
```

The trick is to have an image with both states in it. Then make the div just large enough for only one of the states. On `:hover` you change which portion of the image is visible by altering the `background-position` value.